# Find list of keywords in string

Tags: python, string, list, csv

So I have a list of key words and I'm trying to check if any of those words are found in a line in my csv sheet, if present, it should be marked. The code I have works perfectly except when the line has more than one of those keywords, it won't be marked. Thoughts?

```
import sys
import csv
nk = ('aaa','bbb','ccc')
with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in reader:
        string=str(row)
        if any(word in string for word in nk):
            row.append('***')
            print '\t'.join(row)
        else:
            print '\t'.join(row)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use set intersection to get all the common words:

```
nk = {'aaa','bbb','ccc'}
seen = set()             #keep as track of items seen so far in this set
with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as f:
    ...
    for row in reader:
        #update `seen` with the items found common between `nk` and the current `row`
        seen.update(nk.intersection(row))
    ...
```

Don't convert `row` to a string(`string=str(row)`), `in` operator works fine with lists as well and behaves differently than string's `in`:

```
>>> strs = "['foo','abarc']"
>>> 'bar' in strs            #substring search
True
>>> lis = ['foo','abarc']    #item search
>>> 'bar' in lis
False
```

Comment: I'm converting to string because some of my list items are "partial keywords". For example a row may contain ['aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'xxxxx', ,'yyyyyy'] if i don't convert to string, the in operator will miss 'aaaaaaaaa'

Comment: @AishaAJ For that you could use `matches = [x for x in nk if any(x in item for item in row)]`